# Can we use Seed block algorithm for NFS share and SMB share for disaster recovery

Tags: java, storage

As I know Seed block algorithm is used for cloud computing but can it be used for SMB share, NFS or CIFS share and HTTP share protocols on SAS, NAS, DAS storage devices for disaster recovery?